# IK not working for legs, where am I wrong?

Tags: armature, inverse-kinematics

I'm stuck in this armature creation where IK works pretty well for harms but knees don't curve as they should.. I set same but something is not working..

[image: problem]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legs need a bend in their default position.  Select the armature, go into Edit Mode, and push the knees forward a tad.  Here's what it should look like after that.

[image]

Also, consider reducing the leg IK chain length to 2.  This will make the bending more predictable.